# mypy giving error Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named math_func even after adding MYPYPATH

Tags: python, mypy

i have two modules under package **'code'** .

First module in math_func.py

another one is main.py.

I am importing math_func.py in main.py. Earlier when i was running mypy ot was giving error

'''Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "math_func"'''

but after reading mypy docs i added path MYPYPATH using command

(project_2) p0p029i@m-c02dt1k2md6n enviroment_2 % export MYPYPATH=/Users/p0p029i/Desktop/enviroment_2

i am again getting the same error. Attached screenshot for reference.

[image: main.py]

[image: math_func.py]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math_func` is not a top-level module, as you have `__init__.py` under `code/`.
So you should write `import code.math_func` instead OR remove `code/__init__.py`.

Adding `environment_2` to `MYPYPATH` does not solve it because it still doesn't allow mypy to discover `math_func` as a top-level module.

To have a better understanding of it, consider the difference between the following imports:

```
import .math_func      # relative import
import math_func       # look for a top-level module "math_func"
import code.math_func  # look for a top-level module "code" that has a submodule math_func underneath
import re              # look for a top-level module "re"
```